# State initialization inside a functional component (without infinite looping)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a functional component that holds custom viewport values in its state, so it must use event listeners and measure the window size:

```
const AppWrap = () => {

  // custom vw and vh vars
  const [vw, setvw] = useState();
  const [vh, setvh] = useState();

  // gets the inner height/width to act as viewport dimensions (cross-platform benefits)
  const setViewportVars = () => {

    const viewportWidth = window.innerWidth;
    const viewportHeight = window.innerHeight;

    // can be accessed in scss as vw(n), vh(n) OR in css as --vw * n, --vh * n
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--vw', `${viewportWidth / 100}px`);
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--vh', `${viewportHeight / 100}px`);

    // can be accessed in child components as vw * n or vh * n
    setvw(viewportWidth / 100);
    setvh(viewportHeight / 100);

  }

  // I'd like to run this function *once* when the component is initialized
  setViewportVars();

  // add listeners
  window.addEventListener('resize', setViewportVars);
  window.addEventListener('orientationchange', setViewportVars);
  window.addEventListener('fullscreenchange', setViewportVars);

  return (
    <App vw={vw} vh={vh}/>
  );

}
```

The above code produces an error: `Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.`

I can wrap `setViewportVars()` in useEffect, but I don't see why this is necessary. My understanding of functional components is that they only run code outside of the return statement once, and that only the JSX would re-render on a state change.

Comment: In your case when component loads it calls the function which changes states so again it calls the component again it changes so it . goes to infinite condition inorder . to avoid this you need to useEffect , added the answer kindly check it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `useEffect` and pass empty array as dependencies, so this will only be excecuted once just like `componentDidMount`:

```
useEffect(() => {
  setViewportVars();

  // add listeners
  window.addEventListener('resize', setViewportVars);
  window.addEventListener('orientationchange', setViewportVars);
  window.addEventListener('fullscreenchange', setViewportVars);
}, []);
```

Comment: This is correct - thanks! After reading up on this some more, I would also note that instead of listing an empty dep array, the recommendation is to move `setViewportVars` into useEffect (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-it-safe-to-omit-functions-from-the-list-of-dependencies)

Answer (score 1):

So in your case what happens is basically you call the function it will update the state, so again component will load again function will call so basically that goes to infinite loop

**Solution**

you can [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html), so in useEffect if you pass the second argument which is an array as empty it will called only one time like the componentDidMount

```
useEffect(() => {
  setViewportVars()
}, [])
```

So if you pass second argument

1. Passing nothing, like `useEffect(() => {})` - it will call every time.
2. Passing an empty array `useEffect(() => {}, [])` - it will call one time.
3. Passing array deps, whenever the array dependencies changes it will execute the code block inside the usEffect.

   `useEffect(() => {
     // some logic
   }, [user])`

Answer (score 1):

The answer to *why* you need to useEffect() to prevent the infinite re-render:

`<AppWrap>` has state `{vw}` and `{vh}`. When `<AppWrap>`is fired, `setViewportVars()` immediately runs and updates that state. Because you updated the state,  `setViewportVars()` is then fired again (to keep in line with the react one way data flow which updates the state of `{vw/vh}` and causes a re-firing of `AppWrap` ...which causes a re-firing of `setViewportVars()`. At no point here have we allowed the DOM to get painted by the browser, we are just repeating the loop of:

`init component > getHeight/Width > updateState > re-render component > getHeight/Width > ...`

useEffect behaves differently than a regular render. useEffect fires *only after* a the DOM has been painted by the browser. Which means that the first cycle would finish (`init component > browser paints DOM >  useEffect(getHeight/Width) > |if state aka viewsize changed?| > re-render`)

For more info, check out Dan Abramov's blog on [useEffect](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/)

Comment: If I remove `<App vw={vw} vh={vh}/>` (i.e. make AppWrap render nothing) I get the same looping behavior. So I'm not sure that the sequencing/connection you are drawing between the two components is accurate.

Answer (score 0):

```
const AppWrap = () => {

    // custom vw and vh vars
    const [vw, setvw] = useState();
    const [vh, setvh] = useState();

    // gets the inner height/width to act as viewport dimensions (cross-platform benefits)
    const setViewportVars = useCallback(() => {

        const viewportWidth = window.innerWidth;
        const viewportHeight = window.innerHeight;

        // can be accessed in scss as vw(n), vh(n) OR in css as --vw * n, --vh * n
        document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--vw', `${viewportWidth / 100}px`);
        document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--vh', `${viewportHeight / 100}px`);

        // can be accessed in child components as vw * n or vh * n
        setvw(viewportWidth / 100);
        setvh(viewportHeight / 100);

    }, []);



    useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener('resize', setViewportVars);
        window.addEventListener('orientationchange', setViewportVars);
        window.addEventListener('fullscreenchange', setViewportVars);
        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener('resize', setViewportVars);
            window.removeEventListener('orientationchange', setViewportVars);
            window.removeEventListener('fullscreenchange', setViewportVars);
        }
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        // I'd like to run this function *once* when the component is initialized
        setViewportVars();
    }, []);


    return (
        <App vw={vw} vh={vh} />
    );

}
```

Comment: 1. wrap your callback with useCallback
2. bind your events inside use effect and unbind inside the return function
2. invoke setViewportVars from useEffect with empty array as dependcies

Comment: I see how this would work, but it doesn't square with recommendations in the docs. For instance: "every value referenced inside the callback should also appear in the dependencies array" (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback)

Similar recommendations around empty array deps can be found here: https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/

Comment: After reading up on this a bit more, I think that the proper way way to do this is actually to pull `setViewportVars` into `useEffect` instead of wrapping it in `useCallback` (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-it-safe-to-omit-functions-from-the-list-of-dependencies)